# Applying a material to a model which has preassigned materials

Tags: modeling, texturing, import

I exported a model from Cinema4d into Blender. I exported it as an FBX file and in the file, there are already predefined textures:

[image]

This is how the model looked when I imported it into Blender:

[image]

Any idea on how I assign the specific materials to the specific areas such as the head and the body?

Comment: if they aren't connected, you can seprate them by loose parts.

Comment: Do you know how I would do that? I am coming from 3ds max so this is quite new to me.

Comment: un momento... will write an answer

Answer (score 1):

Select your object. <kbd>Tab</kbd> into edit mode.

Hit <kbd>P</kbd>. It will bring up 3 options

- Selection
- Loose Parts
- By Material

Since you are asking about adding materials to different parts, you probably don't already have them.
If th mesh isn't solid (i.e., body, head and hat don't share vertexes) take the "Loose Parts" path.

[image]

This will turn each part of the mesh into a separate object. They can be colored separately.

[image]

alternately, you can mouse over a part of the mesh and hit <kbd>L</kbd>. follow [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh) answer to color the selection.

Comment: All I have been able to do is drag the hat texture onto the hat. It didn't separate it like in the picture. I tried dragging the textures onto the other areas, but it didn't work. I also tried the thing you sent me and it too didn't work well.

http://gyazo.com/dbcf755f75170ac76567a632ec88201b

Comment: It may be that the entire model you pictured in your question is a single, monolithic mesh.

Comment: which would suck

Answer (score 0):

First thing I notice is that you have two sets of texture pairs, the two images on the left are a main texture for the uniform, consisting of the front and back, and the arms of the jacket, the two legs of the trousers, and front and back of the gloves, and a matching normal map for that texture. The two textures on the right are a main texture for the hat, and a normal map for the hat. I may be mistaken, but you seem to be missing at least one, and perhaps two other pairs of textures, for the boots and the face.

If the object is all one complete mesh, one approach is import the main mesh and normal textures into new image textures using the texture context button of the properties editor. After you have the images imported into the appropriate textures, switch to the UV editing viewport, open the images in the UV editor, and with the mesh in edit mode, selecting the various parts of the mesh and map them to the corresponding parts of the image. Repeat this for all of the parts of the uniform on both images.

A more detailed description of the steps involved is off topic for this site, but there are many tutorials on UV unwrapping, and it is covered in unit 5 of the [Tufts University course by Neil Hirsig](http://gryllus.net/Blender/3D.html). Pay particular attention to video tutorials 05-08 through 05-10.